# Scala : map Dataset[Row] to Dataset[Row]

Tags: scala, dataset

I am trying to use scala to transform a dataset with array to a dataset with label and vectors, before putting it into some machine learning algo.

So far, I succeeded to add a double label, but i block on the vectors part. Below, the code to create the vectors :

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.SQLDataTypes.VectorType
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DataTypes, StructField}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, Row, _}
import spark.implicits._

def toVectors(withLabelDs: Dataset[Row]) = {
val allLabel = withLabelDs.count()
var countLabel = 0
val newDataset: Dataset[Row] = withLabelDs.map((line: Row) => {
  println("schema line {}", line.schema)
  //StructType(
  //      StructField(label,DoubleType,false),
  //      StructField(code,ArrayType(IntegerType,true),true),
  //      StructField(score,ArrayType(IntegerType,true),true))
  val label = line.getDouble(0)
  val indicesList = line.getList(1)
  val indicesSize = indicesList.size
  val indices = new Array[Int](indicesSize)
  val valuesList = line.getList(2)
  val values = new Array[Double](indicesSize)
  var i = 0
  while ( {
    i < indicesSize
  }) {
    indices(i) = indicesList.get(i).asInstanceOf[Int] - 1
    values(i) = valuesList.get(i).asInstanceOf[Int].toDouble
    i += 1
  }
  var r: Row = null
  try {
    r = Row(label, Vectors.sparse(195, indices, values))
    countLabel += 1
  }
  catch {
    case e: IllegalArgumentException =>
      println("something went wrong with label {} / indices {} / values {}", label, indices, values)
      println("", e)
  }
  println("Still {} labels to process", allLabel - countLabel)
  r
})
newDataset
}
```

With this code, I got this error :

```
Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  
Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  
Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
       val newDataset: Dataset[Row] = withLabelDs.map((line: Row) => {
```

So naturally, I changed my code

```
def toVectors(withLabelDs: Dataset[Row]) = {
...
}, Encoders.bean(Row.getClass))
newDataset
}
```

But I got this error :

```
error: overloaded method value map with alternatives:
[U](func: org.apache.spark.api.java.function.MapFunction[org.apache.spark.sql.Row,U],
    encoder: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[U])org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[U] 
<and>
[U](func: org.apache.spark.sql.Row => U)
    (implicit evidence$6: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[U])org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[U]
    cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.sql.Row => org.apache.spark.sql.Row, org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[?0])
       val newDataset: Dataset[Row] = withLabelDs.map((line: Row) => {
```

How can I make this work ? Aka, having a dataset[Row] returned with Vectors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

`.map` is of type `(T => U)(implicit Encoder[U]) => Dataset[U]` but looks like you are calling it like it is `(T => U, implicit Encoder[U]) => Dataset[U]` which are slightly different. Instead of `.map(f, encoder)`, try `.map(f)(encoder)`.

Also, I doubt `Encoders.bean(Row.getClass)` will work since `Row` is not a bean. Some quick googling turned up [RowEncoder](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/encoders/RowEncoder.scala) which looks like it should work but I couldn't find much documentation about it.

Comment: Thank you. With `.map(f)(RowEncoder.apply(schema))`, it works.
(schema is a StructType Object)

Answer (score 0):

The error message is unfortunately quite poor.  `import spark.implicits._` is only correct in the spark-shell.  What it actually means is to import `<Spark Session object>.implicits._`, `spark` just happens to be the variable name used for the `SparkSession` object in the spark-shell.

You can access the SparkSession from a Dataset

At the top of your method you can add the import

```
def toVectors(withLabelDs: Dataset[Row]) = {
  val sparkSession = withLabelIDs.sparkSession
  import sparkSession.implicits._
  //rest of method code
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it didn't work :/ The errors stay at the same place :  `val newDataset: Dataset[Row] = withLabelDs.map((line: Row) => {`